# Automatically reconnect DB when connection lost

Tags: sql, log4j2

Currently I am using log4j version 2.17.1 . But Process using C3P0 does not by default provide a mechanism to automatically reconnect the DB when connection is lost. Currently I want to add the c3p0 config in the config file to automatically reconnect (hint: use c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts, c3p0.acquireRetryDelay, c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure,c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout)

I configure using properties file. In the documents I searched, there are not many configuration documents by file